# A definite integral with inverse trigonometry

Tags: calculus, integration

Find

$\int_{-3\pi}^{5\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx $

My attempt

I = $\int_{-3\pi}^{3\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx + \int_{3\pi}^{5\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx $

But $\cot^{-1}(\tan x)$ is odd function, then the first integral vanishes

Then

I = $\int_{3\pi}^{5\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx $

Now

Let $y = x-4\pi$

I = $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan y)dy $

Now

Again we get an odd function, then the integral vanishes

So

$I = 0$

Is this correct?

Comment: According to the convention in my calculus book, $\cot^{-1}(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.  So certainly $\cot^{-1}(\tan x)$ is not an odd function.

Answer (score 1):

As $\tan(\pi+x)=\tan x$

So, $$\int_{-3\pi}^{5\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx=8\int_0^{\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx$$

Again,
$$\int_0^{\pi}\cot^{-1}(\tan x)dx=\int_0^{\pi}\left(\dfrac\pi2-\tan^{-1}(\tan x)\right)dx=\dfrac\pi2\int_0^{\pi} dx-\int_0^{\pi}\tan^{-1}(\tan x)dx$$

Finally $$\tan^{-1}(\tan x)=\begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } -\dfrac\pi2<x<\dfrac\pi2 \\
x-\pi & \mbox{if } \dfrac\pi2<x<\pi \end{cases}$$